# NodeJS игровая логика и распараллеливание

Tags: node.js, многопоточность

Я пишу для себя сайт-рулетку и хочу реализовать некоторую логику на стороне сервера. По шагам:

1. 10 секунд ожидания ставок
2. Принятие решения о победе какого-либо игрока, сделавшего ставку (распределение денег изменением балансов пользователей - запросы к бд)
3. Возврат на шаг 1

Напрашивается простое решение - на стороне сервера создать объект "Рулетка" и каждые 10 секунд (`setTimeout`/`setInterval`) производить определенные действия (шаг 2), но не станет ли это проблемой если сервер будет запущен в несколько потоков?

Запускают ли node в несколько потоков на продакшене? Если да, то какими способами можно было бы избежать приведенную мною проблему?

UPD

Да, я знаю что нода однопоточна, но: (цитата с хабра)

> По умолчанию Node.JS работает в одном потоке, что не совсем удобно и не оптимально, особенно для многоядерных процессоров. Практически сразу появились модули, для удобного запуска нескольких процессов (различные реализации Web Workers). Не сложно было сделать это и с помощью стандартного API Node.JS. С выходом версии 0.6.0 в Node.JS появился новый модуль — Cluster. Он значительно упрощает задачу запуска нескольких процессов Node.JS. API этого модуля позволяет форкать процессы node, net/http-серверы которых будут использовать общий TCP порт. Родительский процесс может управлять дочерними процессами: останавливать, запускать новые, реагировать на неожиданные завершения. Дочерние процессы могут обмениваться сообщениями со своим родителем.

Вот об этом распараллеливании я говорил. И да, модуль cluster это решение моей задачи

Comment: что значит в несколько потоков?

Comment: И в чем конкретно Вы видите проблему?

Comment: Ну в том, что событие , которое должно произойти раз в 10 секунд, будет происходить чаще

Comment: **Javascript - однопоточный язык**

Answer (score 3):

> Запускают ли node в несколько потоков на продакшене?

Немного грусти: нода однопоточна.

Самый простой способ, который используют на продакшене: запускают сразу несколько экземпляров приложения и с помощью балансера распределяют нагрузку между ними

> Если да, то какими способами можно было бы избежать приведенную мною проблему?

Я не смог увидеть проблему из первого сообщения... все зависит от архитектуры. Но если включить немного воображения и попробовать сванговать проблему.

Как мне кажется, сейчас вам и не нужна "многопоточность". Сейчас вам нужно просто сделать работающий функционал. Как только он взлетит, и начнет ходить народ, и вы поймете что проблема с нагрузкой уже рядом, то там и займетесь "оптимизацией".

Если вы этим занимаетесь просто в обучающих целях, тогда попробуйте разбить рулетку на комнаты. Мол человек заходить в игру, и видит свободные комнаты, где сможет в нее зайти и поиграть (например комнаты на 10 человек). Тогда вы эти комнаты сможете размещать на разных серверах.

А может у вас рулетка не мультиплеерная? тогда все просто, тривиальный балансер сможет распределить нагрузку между вашими приложениями, и ничего править в архитектуре не надо.

ИМХО я привел самые простые способы. Может есть и проще?

Answer (score 0):

> Если да, то какими способами можно было бы избежать приведенную мною проблему?

Идемпотентностью операции: разработать такой алгоритм, чтобы он гарантированно выполнялся не более одного раза вне зависимости от того, сколько раз и где был вызван.

В данном случае вы на каждом выполнении броска можете определенно знать, какой это по счету бросок в данной игре. После этого вам достаточно добавить некоторую точку синхронизации, включающую в себя идентификатор игры и номер броска, чтобы это действие мог выполнить только один экземпляр программы. Проще всего просто завести новую таблицу под это дело (если работаете с SQL-хранилищем):

```
game_id | round_id | outcome
      1 |        1 | 3
      2 |        1 | 4
      1 |        2 | 1
```

В этом случае любой экземпляр приложения, обрабатывающий раунд N знает, что ему надо попытаться добавить запись, и, если эта запись прошла успешно, результатом броска было вычисленное им число, а если запись провалилась - кто-то уже успел раньше, и для получения числа ему надо прочитать его из БД:

```
function generateRoundOutcome(gameId, roundId, callback) {
    var value = random();
    var tuple = {game_id: gameId, round_id: roundId, outcome: value};
    database.insert(tuple, function (err, result) {
        if (err instanceof EntityExistsException) {
            // кто-то вставил запись раньше
            database.read({game_id: gameId, round_id: roundId}, function(err, result) { 
                callback.call(callback, err, result);
            });
        } else {
            // либо все ок, либо база данных упала с другой ошибкой, которую можно разве что пропустить дальше
            callback.call(callback, err, value);
        }
    });
}
```